# Two different locations running as one on server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, nat, local-area-network

I am with a new company, and I am trying to make sure I am understanding the way it is set up on the server.

- There are 2 locations, and the second location is connected to the network and Server (2008r2) with a VPN tunnel.
- There is only one server (no redundancy at all) at the main location. The server is handing out `10...` IP addresses to the location that it is at, and the second location is using the firewall to hand out `192...` addresses.
- When I go into `Users & Computers`, I don't see any `Sites` set up, and no subnets set up on the DHCP server, so it looks like the server is running both locations as one site.

This is probably a stupid question, but how is the server dealing with the 2 different IP addresses (`10...` and `192...`) without subnetting or separate sites? Would it be better to set it up as 2 subnetted locations, or leave it the way it is?

Thanks in advance for any answers to my question.

Comment: This is done through routing, either on a layer 3 switch, or from the route tables in your firewall.

Answer (score 2):

> how is the server dealing with the 2 different IP addresses (10... and 192...) without subnetting or separate sites?

Because you don't know what 'sites' means in the context of Active Directory. It has nothing to do with the server being able to communicate with a different subnet or IP range. 'Sites' defines the replication boundaries for Active Directory.

see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782048%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To subnet means to take an IP address range that could be considered one IP network, and divide it into several IP networks. You don't need subnets here, you have two separate IP networks that talk to each other using basic Internet principles. As long as you don't want network-wide broadcasts from one site to the other, there is no difficulty at all. This has nothing to do do with Active Directory "sites", which I believe can perfectly well handle several IP networks.